# Setting Jquery Enter Key Event For Dynamically Generated TextBox

Tags: jquery

How to set jquery keyup event for dynamically generated textbox instead of static text box as shown below?

```
$('#statictextboxid').keyup(function(e) {
//alert(e.keyCode);
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('Enter key was pressed.');
}
});
```

Comment: This is much easier and straight forward.

<textarea id="dynamicid" onkeypress="Inc_Cmt_Enter(this,event);" ....
function Inc_Cmt_Enter(id,e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
     alert("Enter Pressed");
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the event using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to keep it attached for dynamically generated elements also

```
//Simulate dynamically generated textbox
$("body").append("<input type='text' class='textbox' />");
// Now bind the event
$('.textbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
//alert(e.keyCode);
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('Enter key was pressed.');
}
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/TZ5CY/) with the simulated version

Comment: its ok, but where to call .on(..) in order to bind 'keyup' event with dynamically generated textbox. textbox generated in similar fashion as in facebook posts.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan, Oh... on that case give a common class name to all the dynamically generated textareas and use that in the code. Wait, check my update

Comment: I think creating a function and calling via onkeypress is much easier and cleaner way. onkeypress="Inc_Cmt_Enter(this,event);", what do you think?

Comment: Your approach is ok just need to refine so that only bind enter keypress on text field within specified part of page.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan, Not quite, you will have to repeat the function call on every element you add. where as code above attaches itself to every new element encountered

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan, Great.. All the best :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Your code works well just target text field with specified part of page by restricting binding event. e.g  $("#post textarea").bind('keyup', function (e) {....

Comment: we can use here live() to attach any event handler with dynamic control.

Comment: @Thomas, `live()` is deprecated and replaced by `.on()`. I am not getting your point. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting a static textbox, use the element that you're generating dynamically.

```
var myNewElement = $('<textarea>');

// ...

myNewElement.keyup(function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter key was pressed.');
    }
});
```